# Accessing Internet from Virtual PC 2007

Tags: windows-vista, internet, microsoft-virtual-pc

My Host Operating System (The one that runs on my laptop is Windows Vista). The configuration is as follows -

Intel Core 2 Duo CPU, 1.66GHz
Memory RAM 2.00 GB
System Type - 32 bit

I run Windows 2003 on my Virtual PC 2007. I am not able to access Internet from the Windows 2003 OS, whereas I am able to do so with my laptop directly.

The internet connection is a wireless connection. The same Virtual machine (VHD/VMC) when copied to my desktop which runs on Windows XP is able to connect to Internet.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have VPC set to use the adapter on the host that has the Virtual Machine Network Service installed.

I imagine guest internet works on your PC as it is wired internet, but not on your laptop as it is wireless.

See [this guide](http://claytonj.wordpress.com/2007/02/02/connect-virtual-pc-to-internet/), especially step 6:

[image: Adapter settings]

Comment: I use roughly the same setup but with XP as my host enviroment. You must shut down your virtual machine, not save it, and then you can choose a network adapter to use with your virtual machine.